# Adding a company field to to the customer grid in backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, dbal

Adding a new field `ps_address.company` to the customer grid, works. But when I search in the customer grid for a `ps_customer.lastname`, it gives this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'lastname' in where clause is ambiguous
```

All clear, we know MySQL doesn't accept this. But the first part of the Doctorine class is defined in the PrestaShop code, and I don't know where to change this in my module.

This is what i've tried:

```
/**
 *  Add column `company`
 */
public function hookActionCustomerGridDefinitionModifier(array $params)
{
    /** @var GridDefinitionInterface $definition */
    $definition = $params['definition'];

    /** add/remove columns */
    $definition
        ->getColumns()
        ->remove('newsletter')
        ->remove('active')
        ->remove('optin')
        ->addAfter(
            'id_customer',
            (new DataColumn('company'))
                ->setName($this->trans('Company'))
                ->setOptions([
                    'field' => 'company',
                ])
        );

    /** apply filters to columns */
    $definition
        ->getFilters()
        ->add(
            (new Filter('company', TextType::class))
                ->setAssociatedColumn('company')
                ->setTypeOptions([
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => $this->trans('Company', [], 'Admin.Actions'),
                ],
            ])
        );
}

/**
 * Hook allows to modify Customers query builder and add custom sql statements.
 *
 * @param array $params
 */
public function hookActionCustomerGridQueryBuilderModifier(array $params)
{
    /** @var QueryBuilder $searchQueryBuilder */
    $searchQueryBuilder = $params['search_query_builder'];

    /** @var CustomerFilters $searchCriteria */
    $searchCriteria = $params['search_criteria'];

    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilters() as $filterName => $filterValue) {
        if ('company' === $filterName && $filterValue) {
            $searchQueryBuilder
                ->where('a.`company` = \'' . $filterValue . '\'')
                ->orWhere('a.`company` LIKE "%'.$filterValue.'%"');
            $searchQueryBuilder->setParameter(':s', $filterValue);
        }
    }

    $searchQueryBuilder->groupBy('c.`email`');

    $searchQueryBuilder->addSelect(
        'a.`company`',
        'a.`lastname` AS lastname'
    );

    $searchQueryBuilder->leftJoin(
        'c',
        '`' . pSQL(_DB_PREFIX_) . 'address`',
        'a',
        'a.`id_customer` = c.`id_customer`'
    );
}
```

I've also tried to change the `$filterName` that I get from `->getFilters()` from `lastname` to `c.lastname`, but that hack also didn't work.

I'm not supposed to change the PrestaShop core-code, and I don't want to of course ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old post, but I'm writing this just for those who may come here by change like me.
I don't know what version of PrestaShop you are using, but as of 1.7.0, I guess you can change

```
$searchQueryBuilder->addSelect(
    'a.`company`',
    'a.`lastname` AS lastname'
);
```

in the function hookActionCustomerGridQueryBuilderModifier to

```
$searchQueryBuilder->addSelect(
    'a.`company`',
);
```

Because Customer class already has 'lastname', you should not add it to the select clause again.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed later that turning on b2b mode also add the company name in the customer grid.. . But good to know anyway, Ill probably come back to this post later for solving other problems!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the b2b mode. Thanks for sharing that info!